# Solving a nonpolynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

How can we solve the following equation for $x$ without a calculator/computer? ($m$ and $n$ are positive integers)

$m^{n}(1-\frac{x}{m})(1-\frac{x}{m-1})(1-\frac{x}{m-2})=1.$

I tried to estimate $1-\frac{x}{m}$ by $e^{-\frac{x}{m}}$ and do the same for the rest, but I got stuck.

Comment: Is $n$ equal to the number of factors? That is, are there other than this 3-factor instance? Or in other words, what is $n$, is it arbitrary?

Comment: You have added the tag numerical-methods. Do you really need a formula for the exact solution or will you settle for a reliable algorithm for computing the possible values of $x$ as function of $m$ and $n$? It seems to me $x \in \{m-1,m-2,m\}$ are good approximations of the roots when $n$ is large and the right hand side of $1$ is relatively insignificant. I expect the case of small $n$ to be handled by solving a sequence of problems starting with a large value of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Computer algebra gives the solution:

$$x = -\frac{\sqrt[3]{27 m^{2 n}+54 m^{2 n-2}-81 m^{2 n-1}+\sqrt{\left(27 m^{2 n}+54 m^{2 n-2}-81 m^{2 n-1}\right)^2-108
   m^{6 n-6}}} m^{1-n}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} m^{n-1}}{\sqrt[3]{27 m^{2 n}+54 m^{2 n-2}-81 m^{2
   n-1}+\sqrt{\left(27 m^{2 n}+54 m^{2 n-2}-81 m^{2 n-1}\right)^2-108 m^{6 n-6}}}}+m-1$$

which suggests that you'll not easily find this solution by pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expanding all we obtain
$$m^3 n^n-3 m^2 n^n x-3 m^2 n^n-m^2+3 m n^n x^2+6 m n^n
   x+2 m n^n+3 m-n^n x^3-3 n^n x^2-2 n^n x-2=0$$
this is a cubic equation in $x$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So you mean we can use the formula for a cubic equation, right?

Comment: Yes you can, and good luck!

Comment: This is not an answer. It would better be given as a comment on the question.

Comment: But the Computer Algebra solution is an answer? Senseless your coment!